# How does mocha execute test files in a directory?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mocha.js

Say there is a directory(Testcases), with .js files, some are test files with it() function and rest aren't when `mocha Testcases` is used, does mocha execute only the ones with it()?

Answer (score 1):

How about trying it out? This is a simple experiment you can run in about 2 minutes.

```
$ mkdir test-mocha
$ cd test-mocha
$ npm init -y
$ npm i mocha chai
```

**Testcases/a.js**

```js
console.log('test');
```

**Testcases/b.js**

```js
var expect = require("chai").expect;

describe('Test', function() {
    it('1 equals 1', function() {
        expect(1).to.equal(1);
    });
});
```

And run your mocha command:

```
$ ./node_modules/.bin/mocha Testcases/
test


  Test #1
    ✓ 1 equals 1


  1 passing (4ms)
```

So the answer is **no**.

Comment: But in tests, it only considers functions with it() right?

Comment: Or `test` if you set `ui` to `tdd`. And describe, suite, and all those for hooks.